# What is the か for after だから here

Tags: grammar

新宿区立新宿中央公園は西新宿、都会のど真ん中にある公園。
ジョギングブームだからか、一昔前まではなかったジョギングコースの案内板があり、
ここでジョギングをする人たちもちらほら。

I cant seem to wrap my head around  だからか here, what exactly is the か and what is it trying to emphasize? Here is my attempt at the translation

> In the west of Shinjuku is Shinjuku central park. It is located in the
>   center of the city. Even before this was a jogging course there were
>   direction boards, and now you will find joggers here and there at the
>   park running.

I hope I understood somewhat correctly, please feel to correct any mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「～～だからか」

means:

> "most likely because of ~~"

It expresses the speaker's (best) guess or inference as to the reason for something.  The speaker is pretty sure of the reason but is just not 100% on it, so he attaches the question marker 「か」.

> "Most likely because of the popularity of jogging, there is now a direction board for the jogging courses, which did not exist a while back, and you will find joggers here and there at the park running."

Comment: ahh beautiful. Makes perfect sense. Awesome!!